# Update time for AlarmManager (Android)

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I use AlarmManager to display a notification for an event at the event date and time.
But how can I update the time the AlarmManager sends the PendingIndent to my app, when an event is updated?

When an event is created the following code is called:

```
public void setOneTimeAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day-1);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        long date = c.getTimeInMillis();

        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date, pendingIntent);
    }
```

The indent called is TimerReciver:

```
@Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.v("TimerReceiver", "onReceive called!");
         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ListTests.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    123, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Resources res = context.getResources();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            long[] pattern = {0,300};

            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setVibrate(pattern)
                        .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                        .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notification_text));
            Notification n = builder.build();

            nm.notify(789, n);
     }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution.. I turns out that the second argument to `getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)` makes the difference, even when the documentation says

> *requestCode* Private request code for the sender (**currently not used**).

When a request id is used for each event, the alarm is updated and alarms are created for each event.

The reason is that with two different request codes, the `filterEquals(Intent)` will be false. Documentation of `AlarmManager set(...)` says:

> If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled
>   (with the equality of two intents being defined by
>   `filterEquals(Intent))`, then it will be removed and replaced by this
>   one.

I also changed `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` to `PendingIndent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`.

Comment: Can you please show the full code after the changes? I think you should also use PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE